# mscrm 3.0 - unregister a callout

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-3

I have inherited a CRM 3.0 system with some custom callouts.  (The consultancy that wrote it no longer have the source code, and are not being helpful at all!)

I would like to turn off **just one** of the callouts that happens **after** a user updates a phone call activity.  However, i would like to leave all other callouts still working.
**Note all callouts for the whole system live in the same Custom.dll.**

This is what I have done so far:

1. Found the callout.config.xml in C:\Program Files\Microsoft CRM\Server\bin\assembly\
2. Removed the PostUpdate callout for phonecall activities. This is the line I removed from the callout config :

   ```
   <callout entity="phonecall" event="PostUpdate"><subscription assembly="Custom.dll"  
   onerror="ignore" class="Custom.CalloutHandler"><prevalue>@all</prevalue>   
    <postvalue>@all</postvalue></subscription></callout>
   ```
3. Reset IIS on the Crm web server.

However I can see from sql profiler that the callout is still happening.

So my question is:

Do I need to do anything else to unregister this callout? Do I need to unload the config from the database?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The step I was missing was to restart the CRM Workflow service and the do a further IISReset.